# Centered icons with float:left

Tags: html, css, web

I have a problem with the centering icon

CSS:

```
.icons .overview {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 16.6666666667%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
}

.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    cursor: help;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

And I have a problem with team too.

```
.team-list { text-align: center; padding: 50px 0px 30px; float: left;}
```

I can't center.

Website: http://www.plus-seo.pl/ category "Oferta"
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't float the list element, set them to `display: inline-block`.

```
.icons .overview {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    width: 16.6667%;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. Check this if you can: .team-list { text-align: center; padding: 50px 0px 30px; float: left;}

Comment: That's essentially the same problem, set `display: inline-block` and you should be good. Maybe you should read a bit up on CSS. For example [here](http://www.highchairdesign.com/studio/inline-block). :). Also, if you have a different question, open another question. This one is done as you've accepted it.

Answer (score 2):

give some `margin-left` to your **overview** class.

```
.icons .overview {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 16.6666666667%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Comment: This is only a temporary fix. With different browser dimensions your margin would soon be outdated and you have the same problem again. This is not the right answer...

Answer (score 2):

You just need to replace "`float:left;`" to "`display:inline-block;`", because by giving specific margin to fix the alignment, can give issue in responsive layout.

So your code should be :

```
.icons .overview {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block; /*UPDATED*/
    width: 16.6666666667%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Hope this should resolve your issue!

Comment: Thank you :) But user2076016 was faster.